# What is the difference between Compiler Script and Compile Code in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I do not understand the difference between Compile Script and Compile Code.
What exactly is being done in this step?
Also, why is Compile Code executed twice?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTkeg.png)

I could not find any mention of Compile Script and Compile Code in the Document.
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/performance/